# Wiki search leads to 404 page

Tags: wiki

How are wiki search result URLs constructed?

I upgraded from EE 1 to EE 2 a few months ago and I've found what I think is a lingering problem since then: one of my small wikis is returning a 404 page for any search.

This is probably because I do use some extensive URL rewriting, but it seems then that the result URLs must have changed between EE 1 and EE 2, so an example of those would be great to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I found a solution. The wiki templates changed between 1.x and 2.x from using wiki_home to wiki_base_url and since I was still using wiki_home, I wasn't get a slash at the end of that, which resulted in two segments of the URL running together.